# Unordered list for menu isn't spacing out

Tags: html, css, list

I have 5 menu items, that I'm having difficulty positioning in line with the background.

The menu text seems to bunch together in the middle, rather than listening to the "width" property to space them out in the correct places.

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nmHSD/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="table">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>What we do</li>
            <li>Our clients</li>
            <li>Testimonials</li>
            <li>Contact us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    top:13px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    height:60px;
    width:523px;
    background-image:url('http://www.kitoit.com/new/img/menu-buttons.png');
}
.table {
    display: table;
    /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu ul {
    width: 696px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You might be better of to have a sepparate background for each li instead of #menu. This way for example it would be easiear to expand the menu in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean more like this? I changed somethings in your css..

I used `float:left;` on the `<li>` instead of `inline` and because you have 5 `list-items` i gave them a `width:20%;`.

**Your new css:** *(less css but the outcome is what you want.)*

```
#menu {
    top:13px;
    left:0px;
    height:60px;
    width:523px;
    background-image:url('http://www.kitoit.com/new/img/menu-buttons.png');
}

#menu ul {
    width:523px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left:0;
}
#menu ul li {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nmHSD/2/)**

Comment: Ah brilliant. Do you know why it doesn't work just setting the width?

Comment: Becuase of your `display:inline;` it should be `display:inline-block` or `float:left;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `display: inline-block;` on `<li>` elements in order to be able to use the width, something like that like that:

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think following code can help for you:

replace code:

```
#menu ul {
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

and also

```
 #menu ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 104px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```